# how to get NSPopUpButton selected object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

I'm having a student class:

```
@interface student : NSObject{    
    NSString *name;
    NSDate *date;
}
```

and i have a NSMutableArray for list of students, and i bound it to a NSPopUpButton like this

content : studentArray, arrangedObjects
content values : studentArray, arrangedObjects, name

now I can get the student object like this:

```
-(IBAction)studentPopupItemSelected:(id)sender
{ 
    NSPopUpButton *btn = (NSPopUpButton*)sender;

    int index = [btn indexOfSelectedItem];  
    student *std = [studentArray objectAtIndex:index];

    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", [std name], [std date]);
}
```

is there any way that i can get the student object directly from NSPopUpButton???? like:

```
NSPopUpButton *btn = (NSPopUpButton*)sender;
student *std = (student *)[btn objectValueOfSelectedItem];
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what is triggering the `IBAction` listed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are doing it is fine. There is another way, but not necessarily better.

Basically the popup button contains a menu, and in the menu there are menu items.

On the menu item there is a property called representedObject, which you could use to create an association with a student.

Therefore you can build your popup button manually by creating menu items, and adding them to your menu.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the way you are doing it is the best.  Since the `NSPopUpButton` is being populated by your array it does not actually contain the object, it just knows where it is.  Personally I would use

```
-(IBAction)studentPopupItemSelected:(id)sender {
     student *std = [studentArray objectAtIndex:[sender indexOfSelectedItem]];
     NSLog(@"%@ => %@", [std name], [std date]);
}
```

After looking at the documentation on `NSPopUpButton` I'm sure this is the most efficient way of obtaining the object.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by utilising the "**NSMenuDidSendActionNotification**" that gets sent once the user has chosen the approriate NSMenuItem in the NSMenu of the NSPopUpButton.

You can register the observer in e.g. "awakeFromNib" like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(popUpSelectionChanged:)
                                             name:NSMenuDidSendActionNotification
                                           object:[[self myPopUpButton] menu]];
```

If you have several NSPopUpButtons you can register an observer for each one.
Don't forget to remove the observer(s) in dealloc:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
```

In popUpSelectionChanged you can check the title so you know which menu actually sent the notification. You can set the title in Interface Builder in the Attributes Inspector.

```
- (void)popUpSelectionChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {    
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    if ([[[[info objectForKey:@"MenuItem"] menu] title] isEqualToString:@"<title of menu of myPopUpButton>"]) {
        // do useful things ...
    }
}
```